# HTTP 501 error when trying to use insertAll from Google App Engine to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

**Solved:**  As Felipe suggested in the comments, I'm using EU as data location. Streaming is not usable in EU data centers for BigQuery and therefore I had to migrate my data to US data centers, after which everything worked as intended.

**My question:**
I'm trying to use Google App Engine (python version) to push data to BigQuery. Everything seems fine until the actual insert happens, after which I get a HTTP 501 error. Google's error code sheet refers me to "Contact support".

**Error response:**
    HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[PROJECT]/datasets/[DATASET]/tables/[TABLE]/insertAll?alt=json returned "Not Implemented: Streaming ingestion is disabled for the destination dataset.">

**Actual code used:**

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = json.loads(self.request.get('data'))
        body = {
            'insertId': str(uuid4()),
            'rows':[
                {'json': data}
            ]
        }

        credentials = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=_SCOPE)
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
        response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(
            projectId=PROJECT_ID,
            datasetId=DATASET_ID,
            tableId=TABLE_ID,
            body=body).execute(num_retries=num_retries)
```

Comment: *Google's error code sheet refers me to "Contact support"* and.. have you contacted support?

Comment: I currently do not have access to Google's support, as I do not have a support package. Hence I'm asking the question here to see if there are any others familiar with this issue.

Comment: Then post an issue as linked on my answer.

Comment: My guess: Is this dataset hosted in Europe? Europe cluster doesn't support streaming today.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, this solves my issue. If you would care to write in your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was pointed out by [Felipe Hoffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132438/felipe-hoffa), this feature is currently not enabled on European datasets.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggest: Streaming ingestion is disabled for the destination dataset.

You either try to write to a dataset that is listed as public and read only or it's disabled by BigQuery for some reason, and you can contact them.

You can contact the support [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/) or in case you know it's a known bug, you can try posting an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list)

Comment: I'll see if I can find a public, write enabled dataset and test with that.